# Rest API url with multiple identifiers

Tags: rest, api, url, identifier, relation

I have an architecture issue concerning a RestAPI url with multiple identifiers.
In a simple relationship, I use to write something like this :

`GET /users/2/tickets/46` to retrieve the ticket 46 of the user 2.

But I want to retrieve, for example, a list of operations which can be identified by two identifiers, a userId and a workstationId. Both of them are not related.

For a GET request, it's weird for me to write this :

`GET /users/2/workstations/5/operations` because there's no relation...

Is it a best practice to use url parameters as filter ? :

`GET /operations?userId=2&workstationId=5`

**EDIT :**

And for a PUT/PATCH request when editing a specific operation, should I keep the same pattern :

`PATCH /operations/123?userId=2&workstationId=5`

`{
   "data":"test"
 }`

Or should I put the identifiers in json payload :

`PATCH /operations/123`

`{
   "userId":"2",
   "workstationId":"5",
   "data":"test"
 }`

Comment: Don't you have an ID for the `operation`?

Comment: Yes, here it's 123 in the example. But this id is not unique for one specific work station and one specific user. userId 3 with workstationId 7 can edit the 123 operation as well.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your previous comment.

Comment: 'PATCH /operations/123' allow me to edit some values of the operation 123. But I need the userId and workstationId to know who and where the operation 123 was patched.

Comment: The URI (Universal Resource Identifier) must be used to identify a resource. That is, nothing else besides `/operations/123` should be necessary to identify a resource. If you need something else to identify a resource (for example, any other IDs that are sent in the request payload), it means something is not right.

Comment: I totally agree.. I cannot edit the server code and asked for a best practice when this type of use case show up. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: What a `GET /operations/123` is supposed to return?

Comment: Basic informations about the operation. And with userId and workstationId the payload is more complete.

Comment: Is it a single entity or multiple entities?

Comment: Single one. `GET /operations` to retrieve ALL operations. `GET /operations/123` to retrieve basic informations about 123 operation. `GET /operations?userId=2&workstationId=5` to retrieve ALL operations for the user 2 at workstation 5. `GET /operations/123?userId=2&workstationId=5` to retrieve all informations about 123 operations for the user 2 at workstation 5.
I know the architecture on server side can be a bit ugly..

Comment: But of course, users and workstations are separated entities